# Unable to open 'strlen.S' error in Visual Studio Code on Linux

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, ide

I'm getting an exception in my debugger in Visual Studio Code, here is the error:

```
Unable to open 'strlen.S': Unable to read file (Error: File not found 
(/build/glibc-77giwP/glibc-2.24/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S)).
```

---

It ask's if I want to create the file, but the software can't because of permissions, I don't know what to do.

**My system is:**

*Linux Debian 9.8 Stretch KDE*

*Visual Studio Code Version: 1.34.0

Commit: a622c65b2c713c890fcf4fbf07cf34049d5fe758

Date: 2019-05-15T21:55:35.507Z

Electron: 3.1.8

Chrome: 66.0.3359.181

Node.js: 10.2.0

V8: 6.6.346.32

OS: Linux x64 4.9.0-9-amd64*

What am I suppose to do now?

Comment: I have the same problem